# Make `Ctrl + W` and `Ctrl + Alt + H` in zsh behave the same as in bash

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts

In bash behavior is like this:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> deletes the word behind the cursor up to the next space
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> deletes the word behind the cursor up to the next seperation charcater like `.`, `,`, `-`, `/` etc.

In `zsh` both <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> behave like the latter one in `bash`.

I would like the same behavior as in `bash`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want, regardless of what's in `$WORDCHARS`, and makes the killed words available to `yank`:

```bash
# Create a new widget.
zle -N backward-kill-space-word
backward-kill-space-word() {
  # Inform the line editor that this widget will kill text.
  zle -f kill

  # Set $WORDCHARS for this command only. 
  WORDCHARS='*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>' zle .backward-kill-word
}

# See comments above.
zle -N backward-kill-bash-word
backward-kill-bash-word() {
  zle -f kill
  WORDCHARS='' zle .backward-kill-word
}

# Bind the widgets to keys.
bindkey   '^W' backward-kill-space-word
bindkey '^[^H' backward-kill-bash-word
```

Alternatively, I've released a [plugin called `zsh-edit`](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-edit), which comes with more sophisticated versions of these keybindings.

Comment: Hey nice, thanks so much! I still don't completely understand how the `zle` and `zstyle` functions work, the documentation is quite abstract and technical, but maybe I'll read up on it some day! Anyway looks like only the first bindkey is necessary because `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `H` already works as desired, so no need to rebind that.

Comment: I added more explanation for you to my answer. Hopefully, this helps you understand better what `zle` and `zstyle` do. 

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much, I understand it much better now ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can set the special characters that are considered part of a word with the `WORDCHARS` variable. This has influence on how words are deleted by `Ctrl + W`:

```bsh
WORDCHARS='~!#$%^&*(){}[]<>?.+;-_/\|=@`'
```

However it also has influence on `Ctrl + Alt + H`. We want this behavior to only apply to `Ctrl + W`. But there's a trick that we can do. Let me explain:

You can rebind the key combinations to different functions (see `man zshzle`). And there are 2 functions that actually have the same behavior:

- backward-delete-word
- backward-kill-word

You can also redefine these functions with `zle -N <func>`. I'm not completely sure how it works but you get an idea if you read the code, anyway, it does the trick.

By default both `Ctrl + W` and `Ctrl + Alt + H` are mapped to `backward-kill-word`. So we can redefine `backward-delete-word` and then bind that to `Ctrl + W`:

```bsh
# Make `Ctrl + W` behave like it does in Bash, deleting words separated by
# spaces. We do this by redefining the `backward-delete-word` function and bind
# that to `Ctrl + W`.
SPACE_WORDCHARS='~!#$%^&*(){}[]<>?.+;-_/\|=@`'
backward-delete-word() WORDCHARS=$SPACE_WORDCHARS zle .$WIDGET
zle -N backward-delete-word
bindkey "^W" backward-delete-word
```

Yeah, now `Ctrl + W` deletes bigger words than `Ctrl + Alt + H`!

**Edit:**

Very sadly I'm now discovering that this approach lacks some functionality, when you delete a word, it doesn't get yanked to the paste buffer (Ctrl + Y). Haven't found a solution for that yet..

Comment: You need to use `backward-kill-word` instead of `backward-delete-word` word, if you want the word to end up in the kill ring.

Comment: Yes, but how do I preserve the `Ctrl + Alt + H` behavior to delete only part of a word?

Answer (score -2):

I ultimately found my desired behavior with these bindings:

```bash
# Configures bindings for jumping/deleting full and sub-words, similar to
# the keybindings in bash.

# Jumping:
# Alt + B                Backward sub-word
# Ctrl + Alt + B         Backward full-word
# Alt + F                Forward sub-word
# Ctrl + Alt + F         Forward full-word

# Deleting:
# Ctrl + W               Backward delete full-word
# Ctrl + Alt + H         Backward delete sub-word
# Alt + D                Forward delete sub-word
# Ctrl + Alt + D         Forward delete full-word

# Which characters, besides letters and numbers, that are jumped over by a
# full-word jump:
FULLWORDCHARS="*?_-.,[]~=/&:;!#$%^(){}<>'\""

backward-full-word() { WORDCHARS=$FULLWORDCHARS zle .backward-word ; }
backward-sub-word() { WORDCHARS="" zle .backward-word ; }
forward-full-word() { WORDCHARS=$FULLWORDCHARS zle .forward-word ; }
backward-kill-full-word() { WORDCHARS=$FULLWORDCHARS zle .backward-kill-word ; }
backward-kill-sub-word() { WORDCHARS="" zle .backward-kill-word ; }
forward-kill-full-word() { WORDCHARS=$FULLWORDCHARS zle .kill-word ; }
forward-kill-sub-word() { WORDCHARS="" zle .kill-word ; }

zle -N backward-full-word
zle -N backward-sub-word
zle -N forward-full-word
zle -N backward-kill-full-word
zle -N backward-kill-sub-word
zle -N forward-kill-full-word
zle -N forward-kill-sub-word

# For `forward-sub-word` we use the built-in `emacs-forward-word` widget,
# because that simulates bash behavior.
zle -A emacs-forward-word forward-sub-word

bindkey "^[b" backward-sub-word
bindkey "^[^b" backward-full-word
bindkey "^[f" forward-sub-word
bindkey "^[^f" forward-full-word
bindkey "^[^h" backward-kill-sub-word
bindkey "^w" backward-kill-full-word
bindkey "^[d" forward-kill-sub-word
bindkey "^[^d" forward-kill-full-word
```

Comment: 2 years ago, I answered your question as written and you accepted it. But now, you submit your own answer that basically copies mine, but adds details that are not relevant to your original question, and accept that instead, thus losing me reputation points? That’s not very nice of you.

Comment: Hey Marlon, I'm very happy with your answer, you pointed me in the right direction. My script is not completely the same as yours. I removed the `zle -f kill`, because it seemed to remove the functionality of putting the deleted text on the copy/paste buffer. Also I added other keybindings that make it function more like bash. Also, the `zsh-edit` plugin you referenced in your answer doesn't seem to work for me. I created an issue about that on the GitHub page. For these reasons I think my own answer is better. But that doesn't mean your answer wasn't helpful, and therefore I still upvoted it.